# Creating Keycloak user from docker container

Tags: python, django, python-requests, postman, keycloak

I am having problems creating users using the Keycloak REST API from my docker container running a Django application. The following works using postman:

1. Fetch admin token [image]
2. Create user: [image]

The following does NOT work in python, and returns 401 Unauthorized:

1. Fetch admin toke (This successfully returns a token):
   [image]
2. Create user (This returns 401):
   [image]

I am using the exact same user credentials in both scenarios,and since I am able to get this to work in postman I don't think there's any problem with access/roles etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi could you upvote also the answer thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not givingspace after "Bearer"  so instead of "Bearer"+ token , use "Bearer " + token

you can also geenrate python code from postman :

click code:

[image]

Search for python

[image]

copy paste the generated code

Comment: Hi could you upvote also by clicking the uparrow thank you